# Grep input from file and sum columns based on search

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I am using grep to input a search string from a file and awk to print out the sum of the columns based on the search result using

```
grep -f input data.txt |awk '{ sum+=$2} END {print sum}'
```

This gives me the sum with all the input strings. How do I get the sum for each input string separately?

Sample `input`

```
a  
b  
c
```

Sample `data.txt`

```
a/cell1 5  
b/cell1 5  
a/cell2 8  
c/cell1 10
```

no of lines in input ~32
size of data.txt - 5GB

Expected results:

```
a 13  
b 5  
c 5
```

Comment: Can you give us some example data and expected results?

Comment: Which file is your large (5GB) file?  (`input` or `data.txt`?)  Are they both large or is one of them small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: It bears pointing out that this problem is a combination of two very common Awk FAQs: joining two files on a key, and summarizing on a key. (As so often, the `grep` is basically [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).)

Comment: You should have put more thought/effort into your examples and included cases where `data.txt` has $2 values other than 1 and some $1 values that don't appear in `input` and vice-versa. A solution that works for the example you've provided may not work for your real data.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sum[$0]=0;next} $1 in sum{sum[$1]+=$2} END{for (key in sum) print key, sum[key]}' input data.txt
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

Comment: Of course it did, you changed the contents of `data.txt` in your question after I posted this answer. I'm not interested in peeling the onion with you going through various iterations of your question trying to figure out what it is you really want, maybe someone else will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your files, but maybe:

```
grep -f input data.txt | \
awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END { for (key in sum) { print key, sum[key] } }'
```

Comment: input file 
a
b
c
data file, 
a 1 
b 1
a 1 
c 1
data expected 
sum a = 2
sum b = 1
sum c = 1

Comment: It is giving a memory allocation error. when I removed all other strings from the input file and ran the command, it starts to print out each string matched to a and the value in column2

Comment: What is the size of your files?

Comment: 5GB. If I do awk '{name[$1]} END { for (keys in name) print name[key]}' input, there a lot of empty lines printed out. I am not sure why.

Comment: Of course it will print a blank line; it's just doing what you told it to.  `{name[$1]}` alone will do nothing but add the key `$1` (the first column) to the array `name` with a blank value.  When you print it at the `END`, you are printing all these blank values.  @JohnHascall's answer was to accumulate the sum of column 2.  Try `{name[$1]+=$2}` instead, like he wrote it.  Renaming the variables makes little difference, but writing different code does.

Comment: The input file is a string such as a, b,c etc.The data file is of the type a_cell1 5, a_cell2 10, a_cell3 20, c_cell1 15... with more levels of hierarchy. each string in Column 1 is a unique value.

Comment: So if each string in Column 1 is unique, does this mean that if the input is `a`, and the data is as above; does that mean you want totals `a_cell1 5` `a_cell2 10` `a_cell3 20` OR you are looking for a total `a 35`?

Comment: I am trying to cluster hierarchies together so the I am looking for a= 35

Answer (score 0):

Is this fast enough running againt your 5GB file?

```
awk 'NR == FNR {sum[$1]+=$2} NR != FNR {printf "%s %s\n", $1, sum[$1] }' file1 file2
```

Where *file1* is the 5GB file and *file2* is the file containing the strings you want to find in *file1*.

**EDIT**
As @EdMorton commented earlier, my solution will print *blank* for `sum[$1]` when `$1` is not found.
In addition, @EdMorton provided an answer which will print *0* instead.
I suggest to check out his answer first, as it is assumed to meet your needs better.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok. Let's wait for OP response, maybe he/she even likes this behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree, but that was a helpful comment anyhow. RIP.

Comment: @EdMorton Heh :-) I brought it back to life and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following avoids accumulating unnecessary details, and therefore may circumvent the memory allocation error.  It assumes the list of the strings of interest is in a file named `input`:

```
awk -v dict=input '
  BEGIN {while((getline<dict) > 0) {a[$1]=1}}
  a[$1] {sum[$1] += $2}
  END { for (key in sum) { print key, sum[key] } }'
```

If this does not resolve the memory issue, then please give some details about your awk, OS, and anything else that may be relevant.

Comment: How do I input the file where the data is? I am running this on a cluster.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if "data.txt" is a file as it seems to be, then you could just tack the pathname onto the end of the awk command (`awk -v dict=input '...' data.txt`).  Note that there is no need to use `grep`.